# Use tuples to store information

Tags: python, tuples

****Question:**** Let's use tuples to store information about a file: its name, its type and its size in bytes. Fill in the gaps in this code to return the size in kilobytes (a kilobyte is 1024 bytes) up to 2 decimal places.

```
def file_size(file_info):
    ___, ___, ___= file_info
    return("{:.2f}".format(___ / 1024))

print(file_size(('Class Assignment', 'docx', 17875))) # Should print 17.46
print(file_size(('Notes', 'txt', 496))) # Should print 0.48
print(file_size(('Program', 'py', 1239))) # Should print 1.21
```

I am confused here, Should I use byte, kilobyte, mega-byte in `file_info`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `('Class Assignment', 'docx', 17875)`, 17875 is the number of bytes the document is. You need to convert this to kilobytes (remember that 1 kilobyte == 1024 bytes).

So I'll give you some hints:

You can unpack a tuple like so:

```
>>> file_info = ('Class Assignment', 'docx', 17875)
>>> name, file_extension, bytes = file_info
>>> name
'Class Assignment'
>>> file_extension
'docx'
>>> bytes
17875
```

To convert bytes to kilobytes, divide by 1024:

```
>>> bytes / 1024
17.4560546875
```

`"{:.2f}".format(...)` will take care of the formatting and rounding, giving you 17.46:

```
>>> "{:.2f}".format(bytes / 1024)
'17.46'
```

Comment: @TerryA thanks, I am actually new at here.  I do that's what is in your provided link. Again thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
def file_size(file_info):
    itsname, itstype, itssize= file_info
    return("{:.2f}".format(itssize / 1024))
```

You should use all the variables given in question (its name, its type and its size in bytes) and `itssize` will be the size which you are getting from the function call. And we have to convert the size to kilobyte so we need to divide `itssize` by 1024.

Answer (score 1):

Taking first examples **Class Assignment = File_Name, File_Ext = docx, 17875 = Bytes**

File_Ext is nothing but Extention of the file
1 KB = 1024 Bytes
That's the reason we didn't use 1000 and the solution is here

```
def file_size(file_info):
    File_Name, File_Ext, Bytes = file_info
    return("{:.2f}".format(Bytes / 1024))

print(file_size(('Class Assignment', 'docx', 17875))) # Should print 17.46
print(file_size(('Notes', 'txt', 496))) # Should print 0.48
print(file_size(('Program', 'py', 1239))) # Should print 1.21
```

Answer (score 1):

HERE IS THE CORRECT SOLUTION FOR THE QUIZ:

```
def file_size(file_info):
    name, type, size = file_info
    return("{:.2f}".format(size / 1024))
------------------ 
print(file_size(('Class Assignment', 'docx', 17875))) # Should print 17.46
print(file_size(('Notes', 'txt', 496))) # Should print 0.48
print(file_size(('Program', 'py', 1239))) # Should print 1.21
```